# Play framework with scala and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, playframework

Does anyone know how to get the scala version of Play framework to run in Google App Engine? At this point I'm only trying to get the default app to run. I'm using Play 1.2.2 with gae-1.4 and scala-0.9.1 modules.

I created a default app with:

```
play new appname --with scala
```

I updated application.conf with:

```
module.gae=${play.path}/modules/gae-1.4
```

I added my application id to war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Then I deployed deployed it to GAE:

```
play gae:deploy --gae=C:\AppEngine\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.2\
```

Anyways, the deployment seemed to work ok but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
play.Logger niceThrowable: Cannot load jar:file:/base/data/home/apps/appname/1.352166538901100396/WEB-INF/lib/play-scala.jar!/play.plugins
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.scalasupport.ScalaPlugin.<init>(ScalaPlugin.scala:166)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:100)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:286)
    ...
```

Anyone know what could cause this? I'm only trying to run the default web app at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer from here:
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/k4200/20110807/1312737091

**Short Answer:** Play 1.2.2 has issues with GAE. Need to use Play 1.2.1 + scala 0.9 module

Answer (score 0):

why not use appcfg to upload your app, the gae module is outdated.  I have successfully deployed a play scala app to GAE with these instructions

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html

Comment: I think "play gae:deploy" ultimately uses appcfg. Also, how do you get the data objects to work? Dont they need the GAE module? Also logging etc....